# mySQL - Select Distinct combination of 2 columns in either order

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table with messages between two users. I need to find all of the different combinations of users regardless of wether they are the sender or receiver.

```
ID    sender     receiver   message
1     'bob'      'bill'     'message 1'
2     'bill'     'bob'      'message 2'
3     'mike'     'bob'      'message 1'
4     'bob'      'bill'     'message 3'
5     'bob'      'mike'     'message 2'
```

I need the query to return this:

```
ID    sender     receiver   message
1     'bob'      'bill'     'message 1'
3     'mike'     'bob'      'message 1'
```

Notice how ID=2 is skipped because the combination of Bob and Bill has already been found (same with ID=4) and ID=5 is skipped because the combination of Bob and Mike has already been found.

Comment: I think you can do it like this: select ````distinct(sender,receiver,message) from database.table where 1``` but I'm not 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extract the message IDs you want in a subquery, then join it against the message:

```
select a.*
from message a
join (
  select if(sender > receiver, sender, receiver) person1, if(sender > receiver, receiver, sender) person2, min(ID) ID
  from messages
  group by person1, person2) b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Note line 2 should say "from messages a."

Answer (score 1):

Just use `least()` and `greatest()` in an aggregation:

```
select min(id) as id,
       least(sender, receiver) as p1, greatest(sender, receiver) as p2,
       min(message) as message
from messages
group by least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver);
```